# How did Anna "serve" God through fastings (Luke 2:37)?

Tags: luke, prayer, fasting

In Luke 2:36-37, we read the following about a woman named Anna (NKJV, emphasis added):

> Now there was one, Anna, a prophetess, the daughter of Phanuel, of the tribe of Asher. She was of a great age, and had lived with a husband seven years from her virginity; and this woman was a widow of about eighty-four years, who did not depart from the temple, but **served God with fastings and prayers** night and day.

To my knowledge (which may be limited), whenever we read of someone fasting anywhere else in Scripture, its purpose is to show deep sorrow and/or demonstrate the intensity of one's petition to God in the face of a specific event. I'm not aware of one fasting as a regular practice to "serve" the Lord. How did Anna "serve" God by her frequent fastings and prayers?

Comment: See also : _Now she that is a widow indeed, and desolate, trusteth in God, and continueth in supplications and prayers night and day._ 1 Timothy 5:5. Up-voted +1,

Comment: Perhaps she served "with" rather than "by".

Answer (score 4):

Anna is given the rare designation of being "a prophetess". It might well be that she began to prophesy after being widowed, 84 years earlier. We cannot say because nothing further is added in scripture yet a connection seems to be made. The simple 'package' presented is that she was a prophetess of a the tribe of Asher, now of great age, and she stayed in Jerusalem's temple day and night, fasting and praying. This is stated to be how she served the Lord.

Temple service included many things. It could range from being a door-keeper (armed with sword, ready to protect the holiness of the sanctuary), to fetching materials to be used in temple sacrifices.  Everything that went on in the temple was part of the sacred worship of God. Or, it was supposed to be (Jesus made some objections to some things going on in his day).

Anna's service is at least comprised of her prophesying, her fasting, and her praying. Clearly, she was seeking the Lord in whole-hearted, devoted worship. We are not told what caused her to fast, or how often, or for how long. Certainly, for Jewish worshippers, fasting was not an uncommon thing. John the Baptist's disciples were noted for their much fasting (Luke 5:33-35). Neither are we told what her prophecies were. However, the account of when the infant Jesus was presented at the temple shows Simeon being moved by the Spirit to prophecy and to bless God for fulfilling the promise that he would not die until he beheld the Lord's salvation - the babe he held in his arms.

Anna arrived alongside the small group at that very point in time. She rejoiced with Simeon by likewise giving thanks and speaking to all who looked for the redemption of Israel - Luke 2:21-38.

Who knows but that the general air of expectation of Messiah's due arrival around that time had caused Anna to be much in fasting, with prayer, and that God answered by including her in that glorious presentation at the temple?

We know from what Jesus said about hypocritical fasting that such merely outward ceremonies (to be seen and admired of men) is condemned (Matthew 6:16). Anna, on the other hand, is entirely exemplary, but her private devotions were between her and God, and we are not privy to any details other than the few stated in Luke's gospel account.

Comment: Up-voted. Suitably voiced by an author very much akin to Anna herself.

Answer (score 2):

First, I note that several versions translate the verb λατρεύω (latreuo) as 'worship", eg, ESV, NIV, NLT, BSB, ASV, NRSV, etc.  I also note that sometiems the KJV also translates the same word as "worship" in other places like Acts 7:42, 24:14, Phil 3:3, Heb 9:9, 10:2, etc.

However, the basic meaning is undoubtedly "serve" (according to both BDAG and Thayer), so let us proceed assuming that "serve" is the correct translation.

The second part of Luke 2:37 could be literally translated in several ways:

> who did not depart the temple, serving day and night, with/for/to
> fastings and prayers

- The "day and night" is genitive and thus, the direct object (idiomatically means "continuously")
- "fastings and prayers" are in the dative case and so are the secondary object.

Thus, we could understand this in any one of several ways:

1. She served using the means of fastings and prayers, ie, with an implied "with" or "by" preposition
2. She served to facilitate others who were fasting and praying, ie, with an implied "for" or "to" preposition
3. She fasted and prayed while she served to improve her dedication in the task of serving at the temple
4. She fasted and prayed on behalf of others in need, according to their spiritual needs

Any of these are grammatically possible.  However, as the OP correctly points out, meaning #1 implies a type of ancient monastic practice that what little known in the first century as people did not do these things for their own sake.  I think this meaning is very unlikely.

Therefore, any of the other three meanings is possible and even likely, as they are consistent with Jewish practice at the time.  The plural form of both "fastings and prayers" suggests to me that meanings #2 and #4 are more likely without excluding #3.

In any case, the message conveyed is of a very devout and devoted prophet of God.

Answer (score 0):

### Fasting as a form of supplication/penance

Fasting was not for mourning, but was compared with it, and often accompanied it, and is, a form of penance (i.e. when people did penance, including fasting, on account of some tragic evil befalling them, it wasn't because the fasting is an expression of mourning, but that the mourning occasioned the fasting). If gluttony is a sin, and *offends* God, and eating normal amounts of food is *licit and neural*, then to forego eating freely as a gesture to God, can be an *offering* to God. This is the essential logic. That is, we can offer up our *freedom* to God, instead of indulging in it, freely, as an act of thanks, as it were, to God. And as we know, thanksgiving is a form of sacrifice. Hence, she worshipped God by prayer and fasting, which go hand in hand in Scripture, and are in some ways synonymous, as two forms of supplication of God.

A brief survey of the instances of "fasting" in Scripture yield the following data.

> **Mark 9:28** And he said to them: This kind can go out by nothing, but by prayer **and fasting.**

We also see that fasting comes with a reward, such that, it is a pleasing thing to God, even though it is a form of suffering — the essence of penance.

> **Matthew 6:16-18** And when you fast, be not as the hypocrites, sad. For they disfigure their faces, that they may appear unto men to fast. Amen I say to you, they have received their reward. But thou, when thou fastest anoint thy head, and wash thy face; that thou appear not to men to fast, but to thy Father who is in secret: and thy Father who seeth in secret, will repay thee.

(In the context of Jesus' use of "reward" from heaven, He means what God has predestined those who are righteous to recieve for their righteousness, and does not imply that anything given to the righteous is earned, only rewarded-per-promise, i.e. a promise God freely made Himself, or, bound Himself by being truthful when He promised rewards that aren't owed strictly speaking.)

> **2 Samuel 12:6-23** And David besought the Lord for the child: and David **kept a fast,** and going in by himself **lay upon the ground** [instead of a bed]. ... But when David saw his servants whispering, he understood that the child was dead: and he said to his servants: Is the child dead? They answered him: He is dead. ... And his servants said to him: What thing is this that thou hast done? thou didst fast and weep for the child, while it was alive, but when the child was dead, thou didst rise up, and eat bread. 22 And he said: While the child was yet alive, **I fasted and wept for him:** for I said: Who knoweth whether the Lord may not give him to me, and the child may live? 23 But **now that he is dead, why should I fast? Shall I be able to bring him back** any more? I shall go to him rather: but he shall not return to me.

In this instance, David wasn't fasting or sleeping on the floor because he was mourning a child that wasn't even dead yet, but rather using it as a form of offering or supplication or penance, lest God should be inclined to save the life of his child. In this instance, God does not answer the prayer, because the prophet already spoke, but the theology of fasting is evinced here.

When ordaining presbyters in the early church, they prayed and fasted as a means to seek the approval and grace of God for the ministry of the man ordained.

> **Acts 14:22** And when they had ordained to them presbyters in every church, and had prayed with fasting, they commended them to the Lord, in whom they believed.
>
> **Acts 13:2-3** And as they were **ministering to the Lord, and fasting,** the Holy Ghost said to them: Separate me Saul and Barnabas, for the work whereunto I have taken them. Then they, **fasting and praying,** and imposing their hands upon them, sent them away.
>
> **2 Maccabees 13:12** So when they had all done this together, and had **craved mercy of the Lord with weeping and fasting,** lying prostrate on the ground for three days continually, Judas exhorted them to make themselves ready.
>
> Daniel 9:3 And I set my face to the Lord my God, to pray and **make supplication with fasting,** and sackcloth, and ashes.

We see here the inclusion of other examples of penance, such as, wearing an extremely harsh and itchy and irritating material for clothing, because it is a form of suffering, i.e. something which can be offered to God, just like the struggles of life which aren't chosen, but can also be willingly offered to God.

See also Job:

> **Job 42:6** Therefore I abhor myself, and repent in dust and ashes.

Jesus also teaches that penance can help one avoid the judgement of God, which is implied above also:

> **Matthew 11:21** Woe to thee, Corozain, woe to thee, Bethsaida: for if in Tyre and Sidon had been wrought the miracles that have been wrought in you, they had long ago **repented in sackcloth and ashes.**

We read also that there were specific days on which it was appointed to fast.

> **Jeremiah 36:6** Go thou in therefore, and read out of the volume, which thou hast written from my mouth, the words of the Lord, in the hearing of all the people in the house of the Lord **on a fast day:** and also thou shalt read them in the hearing of all Juda that come out of their cities.

It is explicitly called a way of humbling the soul, which is simply an Old Testament way of saying the succint word "penance."

> **Psalm 34:14** But as for me, when they were troublesome to me, **I was clothed with haircloth.** ***I humbled my soul*** **with fasting;** and my **prayer** shall be turned into my bosom.

> **Tobit 12:8** Prayer is good **with fasting,** and alms more than to lay up treasures of gold.

Notice how this correlates with the divine reward spoken of by Jesus for fasting (again, see the clarification in parenthesis above about the use of the word "reward").

> **Nehemiah 9:1** And in the four and twentieth day of the month the children of Israel came together with **fasting** and with **sackcloth**, and dust upon them.

Again, this material was exceedingly uncomfortable to wear. It was worn on purpose as a form of penance, or offering, and this as a mode of supplicating God to avert the evil befalling them. When one has felt this material, it becomes unavoidable that it is worn because it is extremely uncomfortable to wear, and as such is not merely an expression of mourning. Reading what follows, we see that it contains the people begging the mercy of God.

### Women "serving" in the temple

As with women in Scripture in general, we see only a subset of customs surrounding them, classes of them, and their roles. The ratio of thins men did and said to women is extreme. We only see some details leak through passing statements in the New Testament, such as 'Elizabeth served in the temple.'

However, other data outside Scripture (but also compared with tiny snippets and hints in Scripture), such as the Talmud, or an early second century document about Mary's stay at the Temple, show that certain women (specifically virgin or young girls, i.e., as seen pure, especially from ritual uncleanness that naturally comes from puberty, making them unfit—except also are post-menopausal women, making references to widows in the temple of note) did have some quasi-liturgical functions, such as sowing liturgical garments, for priests or the Temple, as well as, as we read in Luke, praying and fasting, much like nuns serve God today.

Again, comparable to nuns, she remained a widow, which was seen as very virtuous, and which would be superceded in the New Testament period (or rather just prior) by virginity itself (i.e. never knowing man, even though you could, i.e. on purpose, like you can eat but can also fast from a good licit thing). We see this in Judith, where the people praise Judith, the heroine, for her virtues, including "after thy husband has known none no man." It's entirely possible that the "court of women" was related or dedicated to these kind of functions.

We also note that certain women "watched" at the doors of Tabernacle.

> **Exodus 38:8** He made also the laver of brass, with the foot thereof, of the mirrors of **the women that watched** at the door of the tabernacle.

Whereas this seems like an irrelevant, specific detail, relevant only to a specific event, this word "watch" has a much more specific, liturgical meaning. As with all Hebrew words, sometimes the specificity can be lost in the wide range of technically *possible* meanings.

> **Numbers 31:47** Moses took the fiftieth head, and gave it to **the Levites that watched in the tabernacle of the Lord,** as the Lord had commanded.

The word *seba* meaning to watch has, among other things, the senses: watch, stand guard, carry out a [military] duty, serve. Clearly, it means something more liturgical than just look with your eyes.

Inasmuch as we have an incomplete record (i.e. only what was specifically recorded in Scripture), we have to piece together a lot of this, and there is a great amount of guesswork, but we have the 'guides' that are the tiny glimpses we get into things like this in passing statements, and unfortunately that's all we have.

So in summary, just as nuns serve God in a different way to priests who offer the literal sacrifice, they still serve God with the sacrifice of thanksgiving and praise and humbling one's soul, i.e., penance. Elizabeth was, for all intents and purposes, a kind of 'Old Testament nun' in much the same way that Nazarites were Old Testament monks.